# Adding OnClickListener and extracting info from ListView

Tags: listview, layout, onclicklistener

I'm currently trying to make an app which stores some products with extra info in a database and shows it in a custom listview. From this listview I would like to be able to edit the database infor by tapping on one of the products and displaying a new activity. I already managed to implement a custom listview layout by making a seperate listview layout and adding this to the listview, but I just can't figure out a way to make the tapping happen. The activity also has to pass the info from that product on to another activity, so the info that belngs to the tapped row has to be extracted somehow to be put in an intent. Heres the code:

Activity which displays the listview:

```
public class Products extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

ImageButton bProductsBanner,  bAdd, bSearch, bAddScan, bAddConfirm;
EditText etSearch, etAddProduct, etProductName;
TextView tvName, tvAmount, tvDate;
DatabaseCustom ourDb;
ListView ourList;
SimpleCursorAdapter ourCursorAdapter;

final Context context = this;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    this.setContentView(R.layout.products);

    openDb();
    initiate();
    populateListView();
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.ibProductsBanner:
            finish();
            break;

        case R.id.ibAddScan:
            Intent openScanner = new Intent(Products.this,
                    Scanner.class);
            startActivity(openScanner);
            finish();
            break;

        case R.id.ibAddConfirm:
            String productName = etAddProduct.getText().toString();
            Intent openProductsAdd = new Intent(Products.this,
                    ProductsAdd.class);
            openProductsAdd.putExtra("productName", productName);
            startActivity(openProductsAdd);
            finish();
            break;

        case R.id.ibSearch:
            etSearch.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            etAddProduct.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            bAddConfirm.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            bAddScan.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            break;

        case R.id.ibAdd:
            etSearch.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            etAddProduct.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            bAddConfirm.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            bAddScan.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            break;

        case R.id.tvProductNameList:
            openProductsEdit();
            break;

        case R.id.tvAmountList:
            openProductsEdit();
            break;

        case R.id.tvDateList:
            openProductsEdit();
            break;
    }   
}

private void initiate(){
    bProductsBanner = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.ibProductsBanner);
    bAddScan = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.ibAddScan);
    bAddConfirm = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.ibAddConfirm);
    bSearch = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.ibSearch);
    bAdd = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.ibAdd);
    etAddProduct = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etAddProduct);
    etSearch = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etSearch);
    ourList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvProducts);

    bProductsBanner.setOnClickListener(this);
    bAddScan.setOnClickListener(this);
    bAddConfirm.setOnClickListener(this);
    bSearch.setOnClickListener(this);
    bAdd.setOnClickListener(this);
}

private void openDb(){
    ourDb = new DatabaseCustom(this);
    ourDb.open();
}

private void populateListView(){
    Cursor cursor = ourDb.getData();
    String[] fromFieldNames = new String[] {DatabaseCustom.KEY_NAME,DatabaseCustom.KEY_AMOUNT,DatabaseCustom.KEY_DATE};     //Get text from KEYS
    int[] toViewIDs = new int[] {R.id.tvProductNameList, R.id.tvAmountList, R.id.tvDateList};                               //References TVs in item_layout.xml
    ourCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getBaseContext(),R.layout.item_layout, cursor, fromFieldNames, toViewIDs, 0);//Put text from KEYS into TVs
    //ListView ourList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvProducts);                                                          //Reference the ListView in products.xml (already done in initiate())
    ourList.setAdapter(ourCursorAdapter);                                                                                   //Put ourCursorAdapter into ourList             
}

public void openProductsEdit(){
    String name = tvName.getText().toString();
    String amount = tvAmount.getText().toString();
    String date = tvDate.getText().toString();

    Intent openProductsEdit = new Intent(Products.this,
            ProductsEdit.class);
    openProductsEdit.putExtra("name", name);
    openProductsEdit.putExtra("amount", amount);
    openProductsEdit.putExtra("date", date);
    startActivity(openProductsEdit);
    finish();
}
}
```

There are two layout files used, the products.xml file is the standard layout for this class, and the item_layout.xml is used for the listview:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvProductNameList"
    android:layout_width="175dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:inputType="textCapSentences"
    android:text="Name"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvDateList"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="Date"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvAmountList"
    android:layout_width="45dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/tvDateList"
    android:text="Mnt"
    android:textSize="20sp" />
"



</RelativeLayout>
```

Homage for the person who can help me with this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are combining several basic questions in one, here is a guideline to what you want:

- Set the OnItemClickListener on your listview. This event is triggered when the user clicks on a row.
- Start the new Activity with an Intent (like you did). You can add a Bundle to the Intent which contains the key information, like the ID. The Bundle is made to store simple datatypes, so the ID is the preferred way to go.
- With the ID you can load your data in the new activity from your database and modify it.

If there is a real reason to have the product available through several Activities and not just the ID, you can define a static Instance of an object in your application. Even if this seems to be the easier way you should do this carefully.

Answer (score 0):

The list can inform about item clicks through an onItemClickedListener. The listner is set via a similar named set function. In the callback the position indicates which row is being clicked on.